# MongoDB Mongoose find using Map

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema( {
    email:{ type: String, required: true, unique:true, index:true },
    mobile:{ type: String },
    phone:{ type: String },
    firstname: { type: String },
    lastname: { type: String },
    profile_pic:{type:String},
    socialHandles: {
        type: Map,
        of: String
    },
    active: {type:Boolean, default:true}
}, {
    timestamps: true
} );
```

I want to query "give me user where socialHandles.instagram=jondoe" how do I do it? 
Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoose's map becomes a nested object in your database

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(""), "socialHandles" : { "instagram": "jondoe" }, ..., "__v" : 0 }
```

so you can query it by using the dot notation:

```
let user = await User.findOne({ 'socialHandles.instagram': 'jondoe' });
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you supply ‘Instagram’ as var in the findone?

Comment: Got it. It is like const findUserBySocialHandle = ( platform, handle ) => User.findOne( { [\`socialHandles.${platform}\`]:handle});

Comment: got a followup question on this one. How about if ${platform} is made up of two words?